# Оформление цитаты с пропуском (прямая речь)

Tags: цитирование

Вот предложение с прямой речью: *"- Да с Жуковичем эта история из головы не выходит. Ведь на всю жизнь человек облажался. Чтобы на такое пойти - ой какие причины нужны. И главное - все улики, так сказать, на лице."*

У меня есть три вопроса, касающихся оформления цитаты с пропусками на примере этого предложения:

1) Например, после слова "облажался" всё остальное нужно убрать. Как правильно это оформить? Так? *"- Да с Жуковичем эта история из головы не выходит. Ведь на всю жизнь человек облажался <...>."* Или после слова "облажался" нужно оставить точку?

2) Допустим, после *"на лице"* будет стоять не точка, а восклицательный знак или троеточие. Мы в конце купюры их оставляем или заменяем на точку?

3) Если из цитаты нужно убрать, скажем, первое предложение. Как мы это оформляем? Мой вариант такой: *"- <...> Ведь на всю жизнь человек облажался. Чтобы на такое пойти - ой какие причины нужны. И главное - все улики, так сказать, на лице."*

Answer (score 1):

1) Если цитата является частью авторского предложения, то точка не нужна. Тире тоже. Например:

> Victor спросил, нужна ли в цитате  *"Да с Жуковичем эта история из
>   головы не выходит. Ведь на всю жизнь человек облажался"* точка перед
>   закрывающей кавычкой.

2) Нет. Восклицательный и вопросительный знак могут стоять только в конце предложения, к которым относятся. Если все предложение опущено, то и знак сохраниться не может. Вот в отношении случая, когда опускается конец фразы, заканчивающейся восклицательным или вопросительным знаком однозначных рекомендаций нет, поэтому такую фразу лучше не сокращать вовсе или по крайней мере сохранить последние слова.

3) Никак. Если вы убираете первое предложение, значит и цитата начинается со второго.

Comment: Извините, но ответ на первый вопрос не совсем понял. Если можно, поясните, пожалуйста, что Вы подразумеваете под словами "является частью авторского предложения". Со вторым вопросом более-менее понятно. Если я правильно понял, то, изымая последнее (или два последних) предложения, мы ставим точку?Теперь про ответ на третий вопрос. Да, цитата начинается со второго предложения. Но первое я изымаю, и чтобы это показать, использую купюру (знак <...>). Меня беспокоит знак препинания, который должен стоять в конце купюры. И должен ли он там вообще  быть?

Comment: Частью авторского предложения цитата является в том случае, если она выполняет роль члена предложения (обычно - дополнения), то есть в том же предложении присутствуют и слова автора, как в моем примере.

Comment: *Да, цитата начинается со второго предложения. Но первое я изымаю, и чтобы это показать, использую купюру (знак <...>)* - откуда изымаете, простите? Вы что-то странное говорите. Кто вам запрещает начать цитату со второго, пятого, две тысячи пятьсот десятого предложения без всяких изъятий? Кто им вообще номера присваивал? Есть правила, из которых следует, что многоточие используется в том и только том случае, когда предложение цитируется  не полностью, не от точки до точки. В отношении какой-то условной нумерации в правилах ничего нет.